# Сайт в IE показывается по умолчанию в режиме совместимости

Tags: html, internet-explorer, браузер, кроссбраузерность

Почему сайт http://skb.sfolt.ru/ показывается по умолчанию в режиме Стандарт, а http://milliommetr.ru/miko7 - в режиме совместимости? Как сделать так, чтобы у всех пользователей при переходе на этот сайт стоял режим Стандарт? Если дело в доктайпах, проверила все страницы на сайте, везде доктайп есть.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте следующий тэг:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Если есть возможность, вместо **edge** указывайте конкретную версию IE. Например, 8 или 10.
Использовать **edge** следует с осторожностью, поскольку:

> Веб-разработчикам рекомендуется
> использовать этот режим только на
> тестовых страницах. Возможны
> непредсказуемые результаты при
> рендеринге контента страницы в будущих
> версиях Windows Internet Explorer.

Кроме того, если у пользователя режим совместимости включен по умолчанию, то этот тэг не сработает. Нужно будет использовать особые заголовки.

**с помощью php**

```
<?php header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge'); ?>
```

**или с помощью .htaccess** (используется в **[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)**)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  # mod_headers can't match by content-type, but we don't want to send this header on *everything*...
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**Вопрос:** Почему IE может переходить в "режим совместимости" на моем сайте?
**Ответ:**
На это есть несколько причин

- ранее при просмотре сайта была нажата кнопка "просмотр в режиме совместимости";
- переключение произошло автоматически из-за некоего контента, вызвавшего ошибку рендерера IE и вынудившего его откатиться на старую версию рендерера;
- режим совместимости был включен по умолчанию для всех сайтов;
- IE посчитал сайт частью вашей интрасети и переключился в режим совместимости;
- сайт попал в список Microsoft, как сайт, требующий включения режима совместимости;

Comment: А с чем может быть связано то, что на первом сайте мы не указывали эти вещи, а там нужный по умолчанию режим?

Comment: @clevermasha, я описал возможные причины

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробная схема взаимодействия IE и режима документов: [Determining IE9’s Document Mode](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg)